# Yosemite Run Command on Boot as Root without Password

Tags: boot, osx-yosemite, root, tcpdump

I run OS X Yosemite and I would like to always have the command run, as root, on startup:

`tcpdump -i en0 'icmp and icmp[icmptype]=icmp-echo' >> /var/vtcakavsmoace/Desktop/ping_information.txt`

Is there some way to do this, as root, either on boot or on login of *any* user?

Comment: I've never tried this, so I have no idea if it's correct, or even a good/bad idea, but take a look at `/etc/rc.common`.  Seems like you could add something to the end of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer - it was a little different from what I expected, but, hey, it works.

Here is the following code in order how I did it.

```
su
Password:
sh-3.2# crontab -e
```

This edits the cron jobs for root. When you run this command, it'll open a vi editing interface.

To make a process run at boot, and in the background, you need to hit <kbd>i</kbd> and put in the following:

```
@reboot <command> & echo Doing the command.
```

This makes `<command>` run in the background and not halt the boot process, as root. I put in the following:

```
@reboot tcpdump -i en0 'icmp and icmp[icmptype]=icmp-echo' >> /var/vtcakavsmoace/Desktop/ping_queries.txt & echo Now Returning Ping...
```

and then hit <kbd>esc</kbd> on the keyboard, then <kbd>ZZ</kbd> (needs to be capitalized). This saved the cron job, and, on boot, it worked swimmingly!

Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395479/why-ive-got-no-crontab-entry-on-os-x-when-using-vim

http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/07/running-a-python-script-at-boot-using-cron/

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html